# How can I prevent the page from reloading and doing nothing when trying to upload a file in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a folder with a file called `index.php` and another folder called `uploads`. This is my `index.php` file...

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png',"docx",'pdf','xlsx');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
      if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 10000001) {
          $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
          $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
          move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
          echo "Success";
          sleep(3)
          header('Location: index.php?uploadsuccess');
        } else {
          echo "Error, your file is to large.";
          sleep(3)
          header('Location: home.php');
        }
      } else {
        echo "Error uploading file. Please try again later.";
        sleep(3)
        header('Location: home.php');
      }
    } else {
      echo "Error, The file type you are trying to upload is invalid.";
      sleep(3)
      header('Location: home.php');
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload file</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The idea is that I can upload images, word documents and excel document to the uploads folder. However whenever I click upload all it does is reload the `index.php` page. Can anyone help fix this?

Comment: Try submit form using ajax. it may help you.

Comment: You should read up on [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Don't you want that page should not reload here? then you need to go with `ajax` here is an example : https://www.dorcode.com/questions/50/auto-upload-picture

Answer (score 1):

Bro what a pitty.

I just try to copy pase and debugged error reporting,
apply semicolon to sleep(3); everywhere,it will work

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) 
  {

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png',"docx",'pdf','xlsx');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) 
    {
      if ($fileError === 0) 
      {
        if ($fileSize < 10000001) 
        {
          $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
          $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
          move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
          echo "Success";
          sleep(3);
          header('Location: index.php?uploadsuccess');
        } 
        else 
        {
          echo "Error, your file is to large.";
          sleep(3);
          header('Location: home.php');
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
        echo "Error uploading file. Please try again later.";
        sleep(3);
        header('Location: home.php');
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      echo "Error, The file type you are trying to upload is invalid.";
      sleep(3);
      header('Location: home.php');
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it didn't work. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using type="submit", use type="button" and onclick function.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="saveData()" value="Upload file">
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this as well but the button now does nothing. I have put the PHP code into a function called saveData() but nothing happens.